# Standard Gram matrices for lattices

Tags: linear-algebra, mg.metric-geometry, lattices, euclidean-lattices

I would like to define standard Gram matrices, and use them to help me understand the symmetries of lattices.

I define "standard Gram matrix" as the Gram matrix g that minimizes the deviation from Toeplitz and that satisfies abs(inv(g)) = abs(g).

I have obtained Gram matrices for D4, E8, A15+ with small deviations from Toeplitz that satisfy abs(inv(g)) = abs(g) but I cannot be sure that I have obtained the global optimum.  My method for solving the optimization problem specified by the definition of "standard Gram matrix" is ad hoc and I cannot be sure that it has found the global optimum.

QUESTIONS:

-- How do I uniquely determine a standard Gram matrix for a lattice?  Are there any other definitions of "standard Gram matrix" for lattices?  Do you have any literature references in which "standard Gram matrix" is defined for any reason?

I seem to be able to uniquely define standard Gram matrices for D4, E8, A15+ for instance.

But I may have missed the optimum for E8 and A15+.

**This is my ad-hoc method for determining the standard Gram matrix according to my definition:**

I find a Gram matrix g for which abs(inv(g)) - abs(g) is zero.  g seems to be unique up to permutations and sign flips, but I am not sure.  I choose g to have the most positive signs.  inv(mat) is the matrix inverse of mat, and abs(mat) is the absolute values of the matrix elements.

Furthermore I permute the basis vectors to make the Gram matrix maximally Toeplitz.

That seems to uniquely define the standard Gram matrices for D4 and E8.

("maximally" refers to the L1 norm of the matrix elements, sum of absolute values of deviations of matrix elements)

For instance, for the 24-cell D4 = D4* lattice I obtain a Toeplitz Gram matrix

$$ \mathrm{gd4} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \begin{array}{cccc} 
2 & 1 & 0 &-1 \\ 
1 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
-1& 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array} \right)$$

The inverse is

$$ \mathrm{inv}(\mathrm{gd4}) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}} \left( \begin{array}{cccc} 
2 &-1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
-1& 2 &-1 & 0 \\ 
0 &-1 & 2 &-1 \\ 
1 & 0 &-1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array} \right) $$

likewise E8 has gram matrix ge8, not quite Toepliz.

$$ \mathrm{ge8 =} \begin{array}{ccccccccc} 
 &&  2 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && -1 && 1 \\
 &&  0 && 2 && 1 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && -1 \\
 &&  1 && 1 && 2 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 &&  0 \\
 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 2 && -1 && 1 && 0 && 0 \\
 && 0 && 0 && 1 && -1 && 2 && 0 && 1 && 0 \\
 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 2 && 1 && 1 \\
 && -1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 1 && 2 && 0 \\
 && 1 && -1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 2 \\
\end{array} $$

Each basis vector is perpendicular (90 degrees) to four other basis vectors, and makes angles of 60, 60, 120 degrees with the other three basis vectors.

inverse

$$ \mathrm{inv(ge8) =} \begin{array}{ccccccccc} 
 &&  2 &&  0 && -1 &&  0 &&  0 &&  0 &&  1 && -1 \\
 &&  0 &&  2 && -1 && -1 &&  0 &&  0 &&  0 &&  1 \\
 && -1 && -1 &&  2 &&  0 && -1 &&  0 &&  0 &&  0 \\
 &&  0 && -1 &&  0 &&  2 &&  1 && -1 &&  0 &&  0 \\
 &&  0 &&  0 && -1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  0 && -1 &&  0 \\
 &&  0 &&  0 &&  0 && -1 &&  0 &&  2 && -1 && -1 \\
 &&  1 &&  0 &&  0 &&  0 && -1 && -1 &&  2 &&  0 \\
 && -1 &&  1 &&  0 &&  0 &&  0 && -1 &&  0 &&  2 \\
\end{array} $$

The "Dynkin diagrams" are a square for D4 and a cube for E8 as shown in the figure here: [Dynkin diagrams for D4 and E8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRSno.png)

In contrast the usual Dynkin diagram for D4 is a triangle: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dynkin_diagram_D4.png

I wonder whether I have found the maximally Toeplitz Gram matrix for E8 and A15+.

For A15+ the permutations are irrelevant.  In this case I obtain a Gram matrix ga15plus satisfying

abs(ga15plus) = abs(inv(ga15plus))

$$ \mathrm{ga15plus \ =} \begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccc} 
 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  4 &&  4 &&  4 &&  4 &&  4 &&  4 &&  4 && 15 &&  4 &&  4 &&  4 &&  4 &&  4 &&  4 &&  4 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  4 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  4 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 \\
\end{array} $$

$$ \mathrm{inv(ga15plus) \ =} \begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccc} 
 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 && -4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 && -4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 && -4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 && -4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 && -4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 && -4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 && -4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 && -4 && -4 && -4 && -4 && -4 && -4 && -4 && 15 && -4 && -4 && -4 && -4 && -4 && -4 && -4 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 && -4 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 && -4 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 && -4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 && -4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 && -4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 && -4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 &&  1 \\
 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 && -4 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  1 &&  2 \\
\end{array} $$

With this Gram matrix there is one unique basis vector, so for A15+, there are 15 equivalent permutations, 15 equivalent standard gram matrices according to my definition.

But perhaps a different ga15plus also satisfies the inverse equality and can be made more Toeplitz.

In summary with my draft definition of "standard Gram matrix",

I seem to obtain unique standard Gram matrices for D4 and E8 and 15 equivalent standard Gram matrices for A15+.  But I am not sure that I have obtained the most Toeplitz Gram matrices for E8 and A15+.

Again my questions are

-- How do I uniquely determine a standard Gram matrix for a lattice?  Are there any other definitions of "standard Gram matrix" for lattices?  ​Do you have any literature references in which "standard Gram matrix" is defined for any reason?

Comment: This is a very confusing question. First, you are asking about definitions, yet there is no single precise definition. Second, Dynkin diagrams are those corresponding to the "finite" case, there is no A15+ : perhaps you mean Coxeter diagrams. Finally, those diagrams encode reflection groups, or more generally abstract Coxeter groups, in particular, they encode a presentation by generators and relations, and as such are not at all arbitrary. Perhaps the question you should be asking is how trying to determine the orthogonal symmetries of a lattice helps to make some non-arbitrary choices.

Comment: vladimir-dotsenko I am asking how to uniquely define the Gram matrix for a lattice.  I know that there seems to be no precise definition of "standard" uniquely defined Gram matrix in the literature.  That is why I am asking.  Please forgive my confusion about the nomenclature.  I tried to define the diagram I am describing.  For E8 it is actually a cube not an octagon.  The diagram places lines between points representing basis vectors at 60 or 120 degrees.

Comment: No, you are asking "what do you think of my definition", yet you do not give a precise definition.

Comment: The most compact definition is the gram matrix g that minimizes the deviation from Toeplitz and that satisfies abs(inv(g)) = abs(g)

Comment: I agree, "Perhaps the question you should be asking is how trying to determine the orthogonal symmetries of a lattice helps to make some non-arbitrary choices."  Do you have any guidance regarding D4 and E8?

Comment: Yes I mean "Coxeter diagram" not "Dynkin diagram" -- the diagram I am talking about, what I showed for D4 (square) and E8 (cube) and linked to Wiki for D4 (triangle) is defined for gram matrices for which the cosine of the angle between every pair of basis vectors is -0.5, 0, or 0.5 (angles 60, 90, 120).  Each basis vector is a point, and lines connect pairs of points representing basis vectors at 60 or 120 degrees.  Square has a higher symmetry order than triangle so I think that the square diagram for D4 given by my gram matrix is better than the triangle diagram on Wikipedia.

Comment: The standard D4 gram matrix g, given by the tables of Nebe & Sloane for instance, corresponding to the triangular Coxeter-Dynkin diagram for D4 from Wiki commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Dynkin_diagram_D4.png has an inverse inv(g) that does not satisfy abs(g) = abs(inv(g)) and so inv(g) has a different diagram which seems unsatisfactory.  inv(g) has a tetrahedral Coxeter-Dynkin diagram, in which one node is decorated denoting that its basis vector has twice the squared length of the other three basis vectors.  The cubic diagram for E8 seems maximally symmetric.

Comment: Or, the diagram for inv(gd4) s a tetrahedron in which the radius^2 of one of the nodes is twice the others (no decoration is required then; the diagram for a qualifying NxN gram matrix is generally a (N-1)-dim graph in which the radius of a node represents the length of the corresponding basis vector). Either way, the fact that the standard gd4 does not satisfy abs(g) = abs(inv(g)) seems unsatisfactory.  I wonder to what degree the requirement abs(g) = abs(inv(g)) reduces the space of g, regardless of Toeplitz requirement I proposed, how this requirement classifies lattices by its degeneracy.

Comment: What is the exact criterion for "maximally Toeplitz" or "deviation from Toeplitz"? Presuming that criterion makes sense, that would result in a well-defined optimization problem, whose numerical solution could be sought. You need to separate (not conflate) the specification of the optimization problem from exact or approximate methods for solving it.

Comment: The "deviation from Toeplitz" of a matrix mat that I chose is sum_ij abs(mat_ij - toep(mat)_ij).  In other words it is a L1 deviation but I could have also chosen L2, the sum of squared deviations.  toep(mat) is a function that returns the toeplitz part of matrix mat.  the toeplitz part is gotten by averaging the diagonals, toep(mat)_ij = mean_(k-l = i-j)(mat_kl)

Comment: The Toeplitz part of my definition is mainly there to determine the permutation of basis vectors, to produce a unique result. The more important part of my definition is the requirement abs(g) = abs(inv(g)).  I am very curious whether the g that solves abs(g) = abs(inv(g)) for the self-dual lattices is unique up to sign flips & permutations.

Comment: I want abs(g) = abs(inv(g)) to be true for a self-dual lattice like A2, D4, E8, A15+. I want to generalize this formula for matrices that are not self-dual like E7, E7*, probably by minimizing instead of zeroing the norm of abs(g) - abs(inv(g))

Comment: My method for optimization is ad hoc.  It assumes that the g that solves abs(g) = abs(inv(g)) is unique up to sign flips & permutations.  So first I find a solution of that integer optimization problem & then I perform an exhaustive search of sign flips & permutations to make the matrix most Toeplitz and most positive.  I suspect that this optimization method is not sufficient because I suspect that the solution of abs(g) = abs(inv(g)) is actually not unique, but so far I have obtained unique gram matrices g for the cases D4 E8 A15+, using several different starting guesses.

Comment: .. the Toeplitz requirement is irrelevant for the diagram.  The diagram is determined by abs(g) regardless of sign flips and permutations in g. The requirement abs(g) = abs(inv(g)) seems to determine the diagram for a qualifying self-dual lattice.  If a self-dual lattice has abs(g) /= abs(inv(g)) then the diagram would seem to be undetermined because the diagram for the self-dual lattice (determined by abs(g)) and that of its dual (determined by abs(inv(g))) would almost certainly be different

Comment: .. and perhaps "skew circulant" or something else is a principle for standardization better than "Toeplitz".  Toeplitz includes skew circulant.  I need to understand how and why skew circulant Gram matrices arise. Notice that my gram matrix for D4, gd4, is exactly skew circulant and for E8 ge8 is very nearly skew circulant

Comment: My ge8 and gd4 are determined up to sign flips & ordering by abs(g) = abs(inv(g)).  If I reorder my ge8 and flip a sign then you can see how E8 has an (A2 - cross - D4) structure, $$\mathrm{ge8=}\begin{array}{cccccccc} 
 2& 1& 0&-1& 1& 0& 0& 0\\
 1& 2& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0\\
 0& 1& 2& 1& 0& 0& 1& 0\\
-1& 0& 1& 2& 0& 0& 0& 1\\
 1& 0& 0& 0& 2&-1& 0& 1\\
 0& 1& 0& 0&-1& 2&-1& 0\\
 0& 0& 1& 0& 0&-1& 2&-1\\
 0& 0& 0& 1& 1& 0&-1& 2\\
\end{array}$$
This is
$$\mathrm{ge8=}\begin{array}{cc} 
 \sqrt{2}\mathrm{gd4}& I\\
 I& \sqrt{2}\mathrm{inv(gd4)}\\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I uniquely determine a standard Gram matrix for a lattice? Are there any other definitions of "standard Gram matrix" for lattices? Do you have any literature references in which "standard Gram matrix" is defined for any reason?

Yes, this has been done in [A Canonical Form for Positive Definite Matrices](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.14022.pdf). In particular, for positive definite $A$ (Gram matrices of positive definite lattices are positive definite), they
first define $A, B$ to be *arithmetically equivalent* if $A = U^tBU$ for uniomdular $U$.

They then define a mapping

$$A\mapsto Can(A)$$
such that

1. $Can(A)$ is equivalent to $A$, and
2. For any unimodular $U$, $Can(U^tAU)=Can(A)$.

Their (broad) strategy is to reduce to the case of graphs, for which there are recent quasi-polynomial time algorithms. This somewhat limits the maximum dimension they can handle (computationally) --- it appears they go up to dimension 40 at the most.

Note that this problem is thought to be hard though --- it would imply a solution to the *Lattice Isomorphism Problem*.
Efficient algorithms for this have been open for quite a while (there has been some interest for 10+ years), and recently [two](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1332.pdf) [cryptosystems](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/1548) have been proposed assuming (variants of) this problem are hard, so now one can concretely say that efficient algorithms would break cryptographic proposals (so if you find one, there is a more obvious motivation to write it up).

Comment: This paper is beyond my expertise unfortunately; I cannot understand their Can(A).  The standard I proposed is based on an optimization problem, a scalar function cost(U'AU), B = Can(A) = U'AU, cost is to be minimized wrt U, U(A) = argmin_U cost(U'AU).  Please let me know if you understand what their Can(A) function gives for A = gram matrix of E8.  My gram matrix B = Can(gramE8) corresponds to the graph of a cube as I described; furthermore, the unique (?) complete nonintersecting edge circuit of the 8 vertices of the cube may be drawn based on whether the edges correspond to B(i,j) = -1 or 1

Comment: @DanHaxton their code is online (they cite it) [here](https://github.com/MathieuDutSik/polyhedral_common), I encourage you to explore this yourself.

Comment: Oh thank you!  I did not notice that.  It is a very dense paper imho.